# Why Does My App Crash due to Memory Issue?

Tags: ios, swift, memory, crash, retain-cycle

I am dealing with an app created by some other developer. It's a complete app and has a lot of viewControllers , variables and outlets.

I keep getting the a crash after I load too many images from a server ( 200 for example ). I only get this message in the "print area" : "App terminated due to memory issue".

I use the library "SDWebImage" for loading the images. And I tried to find a memory leak using Instruments Allocations, and Leaks. I also used Memory Graph Debugger and non of them show leaks in my app.

Yet when I pop the View Controller ( DetailVC ) , it never fires the deinit method where I have put a message to print when this happens.

I have searched a lot to no vail. I have looked at these on Stackoverflow :

[App Extension "Terminated due to memory issue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190398/app-extension-terminated-due-to-memory-issue)

[App terminated due to memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766142/app-terminated-due-to-memory-issue)

Through out my search I repeatedly see that response that the View Controller must be referenced by another view controller and this View Controller (DetailVC) strongly referencing the other.

I couldn't find that to be the case, although the file for the view controller is too large and I may have missed things.

It's difficult to go through the app and look for strong and weak references as the file is really huge.

is there a simple way ( or difficult for that matter ) to find the culprit and solve my problem.

Thanks

the code is huge (95000 characters) and contains sensitive information thus is not appropriate to post here. although I can post parts of it should you ask for it.

here is the code for DetailVC viewDidLoad :

```
import UIKit
import FTIndicator
import Cosmos
import Firebase
import MapKit
import YouTubePlayer

//MARK:- Gallery Collection Cell
class GalleryCollectionCell:UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var imgViewShop: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}

//MARK:- Service Collection Cell
class ServiceCollectionCell:UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var imgViewService: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblService: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}



@IBAction func btnBackAction(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        SDImageCache.shared().clearMemory()
        SDImageCache.shared().clearDisk()

    }


//MARK:- Detail Main Class
class DetailVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,RateFinalDelegate, PhotoDicDelegate
{
    //MARK:- Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tblViewRate: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tblViewService: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblServices: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collViewGallery: UICollectionView!
    //@IBOutlet weak var collViewService: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var constTableViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var constTlbViewServiceHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgViewShop: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblShopName: UILabel!
    //@IBOutlet weak var lblShopNameDetail: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnFavourites: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewStar: CosmosView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblReviewCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnShopStatus: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblShopOnline: UILabel!
    // @IBOutlet weak var lblDetailText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnShopRate: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblShopAddress: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblShopWebsite: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblShopView: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblShopOpenStatus: UILabel!
    //@IBOutlet weak var lblPhone1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblShopDetail: UILabel!

    //    @IBOutlet weak var btnFacebook: UIButton!
    //    @IBOutlet weak var btnSnapchat: UIButton!
    //    @IBOutlet weak var btnInstagram: UIButton!
    //    @IBOutlet weak var btnTwitter: UIButton!
    //    @IBOutlet weak var btnYoutube: UIButton!
    //    @IBOutlet weak var btnVivo: UIButton!
    //    @IBOutlet weak var btnGoogle: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblSat: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSun: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMon: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTues: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblWed: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblThru: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblFri: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblSatText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSunText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMonText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTuesText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblWedText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblThruText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblFriText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblworkingHour: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblGallery: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblReviews: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnSeeMore: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnBack: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var viewMain: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewSuper: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewService: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var btnWebsite: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPhone1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPhone2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPhone3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var constPhone1Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var constPhone2Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var constPhone3Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var constPhoneViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var constViewScrollHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollSocial: UIScrollView!
    // @IBOutlet weak var btnSocialLink: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnGallery: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var constViewServiceHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    //For Photo Class

    @IBOutlet weak var tblViewHeader: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var switchGallery: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var constTableViewGalleryHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var albumListArray = [AlbumListData]()

    //For Video Class

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewVideos: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var constCollViewVideoHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var videoDataArray = [VideoListData]()
    var switchStatus = Bool()

    //MARK:- Variables
    let globalConstants = GlobalConstants()
    var UserData = UserDataValue()
    var reviewDataArray = [Review]()
    var galleryDataArray = [Gallery]()
    var serviceDataArray = [Service]()
    var ShopId = String()
    var favStatus = String()
    var ShopStatus = String()
    var Latitude = String()
    var Longitude = String()
    var strFacebook = String()
    var strInstagram = String()
    var NotifyId = String()
    var strTwitter = String()
    var strSnapchat = String()
    var strYoutube = String()
    var strGoogle = String()
    var strVimeo = String()
    var chatStatus = Bool()
    var isfirstTime = Bool()
    var receiverId = ""
    var receiverImage = ""
    var receiverName = ""
    var strWebsite = ""
    var shopOwnerId = ""
    var ShopUnqueId = ""
    var HideChatStatus = ""
    var IsChatCreateScreen = ""
    var strPhone1Number = String()
    var strPhone2Number = String()
    var strPhone3Number = String()
    var RateText = Bool()
    var ShopDeliveryServiceItself = Bool()
    var CitySelectedId = String()
    var OneToOneChatUserData : NSDictionary = [:]
    var ShopString = "1159,1160,1162,1166,1167,1176,1178,1179,1180,1182,1184,1185,1186,1187,1188,1189,1190,1191,1192,1193,1194,1199,1202,1203,1206,1208,1209,1210,1214,1216,1217,1218,1224,1225,1227,1230,1232,1233,1234,1235,1236,1238,1239,1240,1242,1243,1244,1245,1246,1247,1248,1250,1252,1253,1255,1258,1259,1263,1264,1265,1266,1269,1270,1272,1275,1276,1277,1278,1279,1280,1281,1282,1283,1285,1298,1299,1302";

    //MARK:- View Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        collViewGallery.dataSource = self
//        collViewGallery.delegate = self
        //        collViewService.dataSource = self
        //        collViewService.delegate = self

        btnShopStatus.setTitle("  CHAT".localiz(), for: .normal)
        btnSeeMore.setTitle("See More".localiz(), for: .normal)
        btnShopRate.setTitle("RATE".localiz(), for: .normal)
        btnGallery.setTitle("Gallery".localiz(), for: .normal)

        lblworkingHour.text = "Working Hours:".localiz()
        lblServices.text = "Services".localiz()
        lblGallery.text = "Gallery".localiz()
        lblReviews.text = "REVIEWS".localiz()


        //lblDetailText.text = "DETAILS".localiz()
        lblSatText.text = "Saturday".localiz()
        lblSunText.text = "Sunday".localiz()
        lblMonText.text = "Monday".localiz()
        lblTuesText.text = "Tuesday".localiz()
        lblWedText.text = "Wednesday".localiz()
        lblThruText.text = "Thursday".localiz()
        lblFriText.text = "Friday".localiz()

        viewStar.settings.fillMode = .precise
        self.navigationItem.title = globalConstants.detailText
        tblViewRate.register(UINib(nibName: "RateTableVCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "RateTableVCell")

        tblViewService.register(UINib(nibName: "ServiceTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ServiceTableCell")

        tblViewHeader.register(UINib(nibName: "SubCatHeaderTVC", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubCatHeaderTVC")
        tblViewHeader.dataSource = self
        tblViewHeader.delegate = self
        tblViewHeader.estimatedRowHeight = 120
        tblViewHeader.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        tblViewService.dataSource = self
        tblViewService.delegate = self
        tblViewService.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        tblViewService.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.constTlbViewServiceHeight.constant = 20

        collectionViewVideos.register(UINib(nibName: "VideoCollViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "VideoCollViewCell")
        collectionViewVideos.dataSource = self
        collectionViewVideos.delegate = self
        collectionViewVideos.reloadData()

        switchStatus = false
        switchGallery.setOn(false, animated: true)

        //self.constViewServiceHeight.constant = 20

        tblViewRate.dataSource = self
        tblViewRate.delegate = self
        tblViewRate.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tblViewRate.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        //self.constTableViewGalleryHeight.constant = 20

        self.constTableViewHeight.constant = 20

//        self.tblViewHeader.isHidden = false
//        self.collectionViewVideos.isHidden = true

        //  self.constCollectionViewHeight.constant = 30
        ShopStatus = ""
        self.addBackButton()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(ShopId, forKey: "ShopValueId")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        isfirstTime = true

        viewSuper.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        viewMain.isHidden = true
        if LanguageManger.shared.currentLanguage == .en
        {
            lblServices.textAlignment = .left
            btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named:"back"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            lblServices.textAlignment = .right
            btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named:"ReverseBack"), for: .normal)
        }
        //        if KAppDelegate.isUserLoggedIn()
        //        {
        //            let userDic = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserData") as!  [String:Any]
        //            self.UserData = UserDataValue.init(fromDictionary: userDic)
        //            UserId = self.UserData.id!
        //            UserName = self.UserData.name!
        //        }
        if KAppDelegate.isUserLoggedIn()
        {
            let userDic = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserData") as!  [String:Any]
            self.UserData = UserDataValue.init(fromDictionary: userDic)
            CitySelectedId = self.UserData.city!
        }
        else
        {
            if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "CitySelectedId") != nil
            {
                CitySelectedId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "CitySelectedId") as! String
            }
            else
            {
                CitySelectedId = "1"
            }
        }
        ShopDetailAPIMethod()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        self.IsChatCreateScreen = ""
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    }

    //    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle
    //    {
    //        return .default
    //    }

    //MARK:- Photo Dic Delegate Method


    //MARK:- CreateNewChat Method





}
```

and this is how instantiate the DetailVC :

```
 @objc func methodOfNotification(notification: Notification)
    {
        if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "ShopValueId") != nil
        {
            let detailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as! DetailVC
            detailVC.ShopId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "ShopValueId") as! String
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Here is the scenario:

I am within subCategoryVC I click on a collectionView cell, this instantiates the DetailVC. within the DetailVC I click on the seeAll button to load the images in the collection view ( this is done using SDWebImage using this method :

l

```
let imageStringURL = ShopDetailData.coverImage!
            imgViewShop.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
            imgViewShop.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            imgViewShop.sd_setImage(with: NSURL(string:imageStringURL)! as URL, placeholderImage:UIImage(named:"noimage") , options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)
```

when I click on the btnBack(back button) and I pop the view controller using `navigationContrller.popViewController()` this is where the deinit message should be printed in the "print area" but this never happens.

furthermore when I open 2 or 3 detailVC's and push the seeAll button the app crashes and "print area" shows

> "app terminated due to memory issue".

I just used Instruments to check for memory leak. there is one leak as it turns out and with these details :

leaked object = `_swiftStringStorage<UInt16>`
responsible library = `libswiftCore.dylib`
responsible frame = `swift_slowAlloc`

Comment: Without any code it is hard to find the problem. Can you create a minimal example how to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I have edited the question and posted some code. can you please take a look

Comment: Tell us about the videos. How many?

Comment: They are all images , the crash happens after I load 200 - 300 of them. each image might be 1-3 megabytes.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the leak I recently found. could please take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

The Apps allows limited memory. I guess after 800mb , app is shut down with memory issue. This is not a true way that is downloaded 200 images for one controller but you can use with tableview with dequereuaseble and sdwebimage or kingfisher. Also you can use thumbnail images because you dont need to show 1 mb image in imageview , this is not unnecessary.

Comment: OK. You are right I should use thumbnails instead. in fact the image are bigger than 1 mb. but I am already using a tableview with dequereusable and SDWebImage. each tableview cell has a collectionview inside. but still one issue remains : after I pop the view controller it never gets deallocated from memory. any ideas what could be causing this issue? because if viewcontrollers buildup in memory it will ultimately crash the app.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the leak I recently found. could please take a look ?

Comment: If you want to get back , you dont have to use popViewController. This func creates a layer over all layers. If you do this you can use dismiss(vc , animated: true).  This dismiss decrease and deallocate all memory

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your answer . the deinit method doesn't run this way too.

Comment: deinit not neccessary. Also your code is not clear. You can use xibs and stackViews.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a retain-cycle. This means that some of the subviews of your ViewController has a strong reference to the ViewController itself or to another object that has the strong reference to the ViewController. When this happens, even if you pop the ViewController it won't be destroyed until the subview is destroyed, which will never be destroyed while the ViewController exists.

If this is your case, the solution would be searching for this circular reference in your subviews and put a "weak" in the variable that references the ViewController. Searching for places where you assign "self" to a variable or where you use "self" inside an enclosure could help.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the leak I recently found. could please take a look ?